# On the Laplace transform $\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}d \left( \ \int_2^{e^{1+x}}\frac{dt}{\log t}\right) $

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, laplace-transform, analytic-number-theory

I've read the basics about **Laplace transform**, and I know that since for $\Re s>1$, $\frac{e^x}{1+x}$ has **exponential order**, then $$F(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\frac{e^{1+x}}{1+x}dx$$
is well defined, when $x>0$.

Let  $\text{Li}(x)$  be the **logarithmic integral** $$\int_2^x \frac{dt}{\log t}$$

First for $X>0$ my computations were for the integral $\int_0^X$
$$e^{-sX}(\text{Li}(e^{X+1})-\text{Li}(e))+s\int_0^X e^{-sx}(\text{Li}(e^{x+1})-\text{Li}(e))dx.$$

Also by integration I can write $F(s)$ as $$F(s)=e\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\int_0^1e^{(1-s)x}x^kdx+e\int_0^1e^{(1-s)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{t^{k+2}}dt.$$

Secondly $e^{-\rho R}\text{Li}(e^{X+1})$  is a bounded function of $X$ for each $\rho >h$, but on what assumptions? I don't know what is this abscissa $h$. Also I know the basic 
$$\int_0^\infty e^{(s-h)x}dx=\frac{1}{s-h}.$$

My **context** was a first reading of a theorem due to Ikeara, but my purpose with this current post is understanding and learning, if it is possible.

> **Question.** Justify and compute, if possible, or otherwise give an approximation of the Laplace transform $$\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}d \left( \ \int_2^{e^{1+x}}\frac{dt}{\log t}\right) $$
>   stating for which complex abscissa $h$ (if such computation is feasible) it is defined.

**Thanks in advance.**

Please read my question looking for mistakes. I hope an answer can help me in understanding the basics of these techniques. This is my first post about this topic. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for your edit **giobrach**. I hope that my computations were mathematical meaning, and learn a few about this theory in next months.

Comment: Also I know the table of the most usual Laplace transforms.

Comment: I would like learn some easy facts and computations from your answer about computations of this kind, of the **Question**: **compute previous integral transform, or an approximation of it and its abscissa of convergence**. Many thanks.

Comment: Was a typo in the name of the theorem, the right is **Ikehara** when I've written "...first reading of a theorem due to Ikeara"".